# How to switch the main domain on multi-website Magento 2.1.0 installation?

Tags: multistore, multi-website

```
    Magento 2.1.0
    Magento 1.9.3.7
    Porto theme
```

We had so much trouble with Magento 2.1.0 that I am giving up. We had 18 websites setup on top of the main website/domain on Magento 2.1.0. Now we installed a fresh install of Magento 1.9.3.7. I put the products in manually into the new install of 1.9.3.7. Next thing I will need to do is re-route the main domain from the Magento 2.1.0 setup to the new Magento 1.9.3.7 (to be like a 2nd website on that install) but that means that I will loose access to the Admin panel of the Magento 2.1.0 install. It would be nice to still be able to get into the Admin panel so I wonder how I could use one of the other websites/domains in there to be the main website/domain so that I could still access the old Admin? (just to make it clear - I am going from Magento 2.1.0 **TO** Magento 1.9.3.7.)